# Best way to minimize a function with a large vector variable?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize a function that is a function of a 1x25 vector (weights_vector). In other words, I'm trying to find the values in the vector that minimize the function.

The function is defined by:

```
    function weights_correct = Moo(weights_vector)

    corr_matrix = evalin('base', 'corr_matrix');
    tolerance = evalin('base', 'tolerance');
    returns = evalin('base', 'returns');

    weights_correct = weights_vector'*corr_matrix*weights_vector - tolerance*returns'*weights_vector; 

    end
```

On this function, I am calling:

```
    weights_correct = fminsearch(@Moo, weights_vector);
```

This iterates until I see the error

```
    "Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded
         - increase MaxFunEvals option."
```

Which leads me to believe that I'm not minimizing correctly. What's going on?

Comment: Why in the name of god and little green apples are you using evalin to bring your variables into a function? This will be incredibly inefficient and for no good reason. Learn how to use anonymous functions, and you will profit hugely.

Comment: I know it isn't the best practice, but do you have a suggestion as to a proper minimizing function for this problem?

Comment: Could you perhaps post the contents of `weight_vector`, `tolerance`, `corr_matrix` and `returns`? Then I can play around a bit better...

Answer (score 3):

Use of evalin here is silly. Multiple calls to evalin will be inefficient for no reason. If you will make the effort to learn to use evalin for the wrong purpose, instead, make the effort to learn how to use function handles.

You need not even define an m-file, although you could do so. A simple function handle will suffice.

```
Moo = @(w_v) w_v'*corr_matrix*w_v-tolerance*returns'*w_v;
```

Then call a better optimizer. Use of fminsearch on a 25 variable problem is INSANE. The optimization toolbox is worth the investment if you will do optimization a lot.

```
weights_correct = fminunc(@Moo, weights_vector);
```

Or, you can do it all in one line.

```
weights_correct = fminunc(@(w_v) w_v'*corr_matrix*w_v-tolerance*returns'*w_v, weights_vector);
```

See that when you create the function handle here, MATLAB passes in the values of those arrays.

Finally, the problem with max function evals is a symptom of what you are doing. 25 variables is too much to expect convergence in any reasonable amount of time for fminsearch. You can change the limit of course, but better is to use the right tool to begin with.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. However, when I switch from fminsearch to fminunc, I now get the error `fminunc stopped because it cannot decrease the objective function
along the current search direction.` saying `Local minimum possible.` The possible solution that it returns only changes several weights from their default position, whereas fminsearch changes all of them. Why they have such different solutions?

Comment: You have not given us/me any information about the values of tolerance and the returns vector. I assume that corr_matrix is a correlation matrix, but it may be quite strange looking. In some quick testing on random problems of this sort, fminunc converges quickly to a reliable solution, and in a tiny fraction of the time required for fminsearch to fail due to insufficient function evaluations. Worse, even if I allow fminsearch to go much longer, it will still not yield the accuracy that fminunc does unless I let it run for a terribly long time. So either look at the parameters, or help us out.

Answer (score 2):

You are exceeding the default number of function evaluations.  You could change that using

```
weights_correct = fminsearch(@Moo, weights_vector, optimset('MaxFunEvals', num);
```

where `num` is some number you specify.  The default is [`200*numberOfVariables`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fminsearch.html).

I am certainly not an expert, and please, somebody correct me, but 25 variables seems like a lot to ask for an optimization routine.

Comment: No, 25 variables is NOT a lot, for many optimizers. For fminsearch, it is virtually impossible, insane.

Comment: Thanks woodchips.  Something like particle swam is better for high dimensional data, right?

Comment: Particle swarms are one option, a stochastic optimizer. As with all stochastic optimizers, they have good and bad attributes. Optimization TB tools like fminunc are better if you want an accurate result to many digits. But a PSO may help you to converge to a (possibly) global solution if there are many local solutions. No guarantee of course. A PSO may also be robust to some issues with the objective that would cause fminunc to die (differentiability, for example.) Any such optimizer is only as good as your starting values, so start too far into the woods and you should expect poor results.